# Finding the number of test methods in a JUnit test class

Tags: java, android, junit

How I can get the number of total test methods in a JUnit test class?

There exists a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535929/to-find-the-number-of-test-methods-in-a-junit-testcase) which was for JUnit4. As I am using JUnit3, is there any way in [junit3](/questions/tagged/junit3) to get the number of test methods?

While running the junit test project, JUnit window usually shows the total number of methods on the top. That means it counts the number of test methods itself. Is it possible to get from it?

Comment: in the similar question you mentioned is an answer which uses reflection. that would be my approach too. it is independent from the jUnit version

Comment: @ManuelJain it's not completely independent from the jUnit version because you still have to count the actual test methods. In jUnit3 they have to be named "testXXX" while in jUnit4 they have to be annotated with `@Test`

Comment: oh good to know, thanks. i was wrong and sure that they are always annotated with @Test ... but you can still cover the search for the methodPrefix in a reflection approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection.

The `Class` class in Java has the method `getMethods()` which you can use to get all the methods for the given class (which will be your JUnit class).

Then for each method you should check if it's a test method (IIRC the test methods in JUnit3 are those that start with "test")

Comment: Before I tried to get the number of test methods using getMethods().length. But it returned 1130, where my class has 1065 methods. I'm wondering where the other 65 methods comes from.

Comment: @Shahid The extra methods come from the superclass of your test class (probably `TestCase`). Don't forget that you still need to count the actual test methods and you have to do that by checking the name of each method. This last step will filter out all the extra methods from `TestCase` that `getMethods()` returns. It will also filter out any public method that isn't a test